# Agrupar valores de una columna y promediar los de otra con base en el agrupamiento en Pandas Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe con los siguientes datos

```
     price     neighbourhood
0   $2,331.00   San Rafael
1   $4,457.00   Roma Norte
2   $809.00     San Rafael
3   $1,932.00   Roma Norte
4   $1,364.00   Coyoacán
5   $1,202.00   Coyoacán
```

Busco crear un nuevo dataframe que contenga en una columna el agrupamiento de los valores de "neighbourhood" (sólo una fila por valor único) y en otras columnas el promedio, la media, los percentiles y la moda de ser posible de los datos en la columna "price". Algo así

He logrado sacar los datos individuales por valor en "neighbourhood" creando filtros con iloc, pero no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo todo en un conjunto en un mismo dataframe, sin la necesidad de pegar los dataframes que ya hice (puesto que tengo más de mil registros únicos). Por lo que buscaba la forma de hacerlo todo de una sentada, de ser posible, claro.

Para sacar los datos que busco sólo lo he logrado colonia por colonia en un dataframe diferente, con este código

```
df_roma_norte = df[df["neighbourhood] == "Roma Norte"]
 
df_roma_norte[df_roma_norte.columns[0:1]] = df_roma_norte[df_roma_norte.columns[0:1]].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
df_roma_norte.describe()
```

Y lo que sale

```
         price
count   1747.000000
mean    1524.350887
std     2843.552880
min     0.000000
25%     591.000000
50%     1083.000000
75%     1716.000000
max 98381.00000
```

lo copio y lo pego de manera manual, haciendo esto para cada uno de los datos únicos que tengo en la columna "neighbourhood". Termino con cientos de dataframes. Muy poco práctico. No he podido lograr que las operaciones que pandas logra en un describe() apliquen para datos agrupados como valores únicos en mi columna "neighbourhood".

Lo que yo busco es obtener esto, donde Pandas hizo las operaciones agrupando todos los valores de "neighbourhood" y haciendo las operaciones en describe, pero no para todo el dataframe, sino para los grupos de datos de "neighbourhood" (Los percentiles y promedios de los precios de San Rafael, los percentiles y promedios de Roma Norte, etc:

```
neighbourhood  mean   25%   50%   75%   etc
San Rafael     1570   100   500   1200
Roma Norte     3194.5 200   600   1500  
Coyoacán       1283   50    400   1000
```

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado para sacar los promedios? Específicamente tu duda es: ¿Cómo conseguir los valores no repetidos de una columna?

Comment: Lo logro pero de manera individual por cada una de las colonias, vía esto

`df_roma_norte = df[df["neighbourhood] == "Roma Norte"]
 
df_roma_norte[df_roma_norte.columns[0:1]] = df_roma_norte[df_roma_norte.columns[0:1]].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
df_roma_norte.describe()``

Y lo que sale lo copio y lo pego de manera manual. Muy poco práctico

Comment: Me refiero a que estaría bien que adjuntaras el código con el que has intentado y el resultado que recibes de ese código.

Comment: Listo, edité el código con lo que he intentado y me lo soluciona de manera poco práctica.

Comment: Ok, ya leí tu respuesta de nuevo. Por lo que entiendo ocupas obtener una serie de Pandas con los valores de la fila `neighbourhood` **sin repetirse**. ¿Esto es correcto?

Comment: Y además para cada uno de esos valores únicos otras columnas donde se coloquen las desviaciones stándar, percentiles, promedios, medianas y modas, ya que cada registro de neighbourhood tiene una serie de precios en la columna "price" que son con los que debo hacer operaciones. Algo como lo que pongo en mi último bloque de código en la pregunta, con la edición que acabo de hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una respuesta un poco más práctica a mi propia pregunta.

Tendría que agrupar los valores y a partir de ello crear una operación. Lo malo es que la operación tiene que hacerse por cada resultado que busque (promedio, moda, mediana, etc). Lo bueno es que con eso se reduce mucho el número de dataframes que tengo que crear (por colonia eran cientos, de esta forma son como mínimo 5).

```
df_colonia_y_precio = df[["price","neighbourhood"]]
df_promedio = df_colonia_y_precio.groupby("neighbourhood", as_index=False).mean()
df_mediana = df_colonia_y_precio.groupby("neighbourhood", as_index=False).median()
df_totales = df_colonia_y_precio.groupby("neighbourhood", as_index=False).count()
df_todos_los_datos = pd.merge(df_promedio, df_mediana, on="neighbourhood")
df_todos_los_datos = pd.merge(df_todos_los_datos, df_totales, on ="neighbourhood")
df_todos_los_datos.columns= ["colonia", "promedio", "mediana", "total_de_espacios"]
```

Y esto devuelve este dataframe:

```
     colonia                   promedio       mediana        total_de_espacios
0   Acacias/Actipan            1072.402597    646.0              77
1   Alamos                     589.680851     490.0              141
2   Americas Unidos/Del Lago   619.897436     446.0              39
3   Anzures                    1178.327451    1048.0             510
4   Asturias                   600.603448     495.0              36
```

Muchas gracias a todos.